# metacharacter processing for default value in variable expansion

Tags: shell

When a default value is provided for a variable expansion (e.g. `${varname-default}`), how are the characters that make up `default` meant to be interpreted?

Naively, I would have guessed that variable substitution (e.g. $b), and expansion of quote-like characters `'`, `"`, `\` would occur in this context ... but it appears that expansion of quote-like characters does not always occur.

For example,

```
> echo x${a-''}y
xy
```

but

```
> echo x"${a-''}"y 
x''y
```

I expected `xy` in both cases, since construction that expand variables like `${a-$PATH}` and `( BRACE='}'; echo ${a-$BRACE} )`, work fine.

However `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release` and ... the latest version of `mksh` both have the same behavior where `''` is included literally in the output for the second example.

Comment: It's expected behavior and in POSIX spec http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `${parameter:-[word]}` expansion is subject to several expansions:

From [man bash](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> In each of the cases below, **word** is subject to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

From [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> **word** shall be subjected to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

Both report the same, and both do **not include** "quote removal".

The quotes get removed **after** the expansion of the whole variable has already been done. However, it is difficult to show exactly how that is done:

```
$ sh
$ unset b
$ set -x
+ set -x
$ echo 1 ${b-e}
+ echo 1 e
1 e
$ echo 2 ${b-"e"}
+ echo 2 e
2 e
$ echo 3 ${b-'e'}
+ echo 3 e
3 e
$ echo 4 "${b-e}"
+ echo 4 e
4 e
$ echo 5 "${b-"e"}"
+ echo 5 e
5 e
$ echo 6 "${b-'e'}"
+ echo 6 'e'
6 'e'
$ set +x
+ set +x
```

Or:

```
$ $ set -x; echo 1 x${b-e}y; echo 2 x${b-"e"}y; echo 3 x${b-'e'}y; echo 4 "x${b-e}y"; echo 5 "x${b-"e"}y"; echo 6 "x${b-'e'}y"; set +x
+ echo 1 xey
1 xey
+ echo 2 xey
2 xey
+ echo 3 xey
3 xey
+ echo 4 xey
4 xey
+ echo 5 xey
5 xey
+ echo 6 x'e'y
6 x'e'y
+ set +x
$
```